# Wrong offsetParent and offsetleft for div with `position:static`

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

Assume I have a page with folowing structure:

```html
<div id="page">
    <div class="someblock">
        ....
        <div class="container">
            <span>January</span>
            <span>February</span>
            <span>March</span>
            ...
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
#page {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.someblock {
    margin-left:500px;
}
.container span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

now I want to get offset of one of `<span>`

```js
var pos = $(".container span").first().offset().left;
```

It is assumed that `pos` have to be 0 but real value is something about 1000. After searching the problem I've found that `offsetParent` of `<span>` isn't `.container` but `#page`. Why?!! After further searches I've found the only difference between elements is `position`. It is `relative` for `#page` and `static` for `.contaier` (default value by browser). The temporary solution is

```css
div {
    position:relative;
}
```

But I don't want this change. So my question - how to get offset of an element although it has `position:static`?

Comment: do you have another `.container` on page?

Comment: No, there is only one `.container`

Comment: look at that http://jsfiddle.net/5yxwmL95/ , expand `result area` and run again, you can see value is change.

Comment: Yes @Waki that was not so good example just because all divs begins from 0; I updated the example, added some margins to parent blocks

Comment: don't see difference http://jsfiddle.net/5yxwmL95/1/ you trying get pos of first span, right?

Comment: Yes, jsfiddle says 508 in my case but `pos` have to be 0 (offset of first span relative to its parent)

Answer (score 0):

You have to display all elements clearly, So add this :

```
 div {
    display:block;
 }
 .container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
 }
```

Comment: Sure, all divs are block elements.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try once more

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
var pos = $(".container").offset().left - $(".container span").first().offset().left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yxwmL95/3/

Comment: I use this code inside onReady, just omitted that for crear source code